# Create a new private folder

Tags: windows-10, permissions, file-permissions

I have read [ZDnet's article about not moving User profile directories to another drive](http://www.zdnet.com/article/dont-move-your-windows-user-profiles-folder-to-another-drive/) and I can see the logic in not going too far outside what Microsoft recommends.

Still, I would like to create separate folders on a new big drive that each user can maintain privately, as though it was their profile directory.  I would likely even follow the recommendation of that article and move the location of some of the "magic" folders like `Downloads`, `Desktop` and the like to be in this new folder on, say, the `D` drive.

Currently, if I create a new folder, say, `D:\Users\user1` as `user1` then login as `user2` I can still navigate into `D:\Users\user1` and see all the files there, unlike going into `C:\Users\user1`.  I would like to recreate that inability to navigate within.  In a *nix context I'd remove the read and execute bits on the directory for `other` and/or `group`, but I'm not sure the right/best way to do this on an NTFS drive under Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy to accomplish.

Right click on `D:\Users\user1` and select Properties.  Then select the Security tab.  This will show you the Groups and usernames of those who have permission to that folder in the top half of the dialog box.  You can click Edit to modify these entries.  Add the user who will have access to that folder.  Give them Full Control.  You should leave System, but remove anything else you see.  System allows Window's processes to run on this folder.  This will limit access access to just that user and Windows itself.  Apply, and it will ask if you want to do it for all subfolders and files, which you should.

Now, here is the kicker, anyone who is an administrator on the machine can still gain access to that folder.  The keyword here is *gain*, there is a process to it and it leaves a trail if they did it.  You can take it a step further and use folder encryption, but that is out of scope for the question.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot.  The only additional step I had to take was to change the `D:\Users\user1` to not inherit permissions from the parent, otherwise I wasn't allowed to remove the users from the permissions list.

Comment: oops, forgot that.  Im old, I cant remember everything.